# Python - check if a letter is in a list

Tags: python, string, list, recursion

If a letter (string) is in a list, 
    find_letter(['o', ['hello', 'c', 'bye']), 
return True, if not return False.

```
def find_letter(lst):

    lst=['o','hello', 1]
    n='o'

    if not lst:          
        return 0

    elif lst[0] == n:
        return True

    elif find_letter(lst[0:]):
        return True

    else: 
        return False


print(find_letter(lst))
```

It does return 'True', but I am not sure if this is the right way to do this. Maybe there's a better way? In the second elif-statement, is python going through all the elements in the list if the first one doesn't contain the letter? The function must be recursive.

Comment: `is python going through all the elements in the list if the first one doesn't contain the letter` - You can use `print` statements to confirm that yourself :-)

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow, can you please fix your indentation?

Comment: `list` is a type in python so it is a build-in. Do not use that as a variable name otherwise you will override existing python type.

Comment: Your recursive funtion looks fine, but there is a simple error in it. In `elif find_letter(lst[0:])`, you are giving the same list to the `find_letter` function. You must skip the first element (zero indexed element) and return the others. You must use list slicing correctly.

Comment: @FallenAngel I tried (lst[1:)] and (lst[:-1]), none of them worked.

Comment: @raspberrysupreme because you are re-setting `lst` value on the first line again and your list sets to the initial value again. Move `lst` our of the function and define it before calling `find_letter`

Comment: @FallenAngel So now I have moved lst=['o','hello', 1] and n='o' out of the function. And I wrote elif find_letter(lst[1:]): is this the right way to do it?

Comment: And why do I have to move lst out of the function? Im new to programming, and not really sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your error

```
def find_letter(lst):  # You receive your list as lst
    lst=['o','hello', 1]  # Opppsss! You override it. It does not matter what you receive with lst above, now its value is ['o','hello', 1]
    n='o'
```

So in `find_letter(lst[0:])`, you use list slicing, but on `lst=['o','hello', 1]` line, you override it again and you always execute your search on the first element of the list.

```
n = "o"  # you can set this too, but this is optional
def find_letter(lst):
    # do not set a value to lst in here

    if not lst:          
        return 0

    elif lst[0] == n:  # You checked first element in here
        return True

    elif find_letter(lst[1:]):  # since you checked the first element, skip it and return the orher elements of the list
        return True

    else: 
        return False

lst = ['o','hello', 1]
print find_letter(lst)
```

Answer (score 19):

I think the most pythonic approach would be to use

```
def find_letter(letter, lst):
    return any(letter in word for word in lst)
```

The beauty of this is that it iterates over `lst` and returns as soon as one of the words in that list contains `letter`. Also, it doesn't need to recurse.

This returns `False` instead of `0` if `lst` is empty, though (unlike your program) but since `False` evaluates to `0` anyway (and vice versa), that's not really an issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, the OP has just edited his question to add 'the function must be recursive'!

Comment: @Ben: Oh, bad luck. Yay for forcing students to learn recursion on examples that don't need recursion at all. Unless we're dealing with nested lists.

Answer (score 1):

Since you need a recursive version:

*Short version*

```
def find_letter(let, lst):
    return (lst or False) and \
           ((isinstance(lst[0], str) and let in lst[0]) or find_letter(let, lst[1:]))
```

*More explicit version*

```
def find_letter(let, lst):
    if lst:
        e = lst[0]
        return (isinstance(e, str) and let in e) or find_letter(let, lst[1:])
    return False
```

*Even more explicit version*

```
def find_letter(let, lst):
    if lst:
        e = lst[0]
        if isinstance(e, str) and let in e:
            return True
        return find_letter(let, lst[1:])
    return False
```

Note that I leave out a couple of `else:` because they are not necessary after a `return` statement. If you don't want to test for a letter in a string, but just for equality, replace `let in ...` by  `let == ...`.

Answer (score 0):

**You want to find the Membership**

Please refer this code to resolve your problem.
**Suppose**

```
list1 = ['physics', 'chemistry', 1997, 2000];
list2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ];

print "list1[0]: ", list1[0]
print "list2[1:5]: ", list2[1:5]
print 3 in list2
```

**Output:**

```
list1[0]:  physics
list2[1:5]:  [2, 3, 4, 5]
True
```

Answer (score 0):

Just realized OP wants to check *A string* only
You can define a function and match the string in a list recursively like this:

```
def plist(lst, n):
    # loop inside the list
    for each in lst:
        # if "each" is also a list (nested), check inside that list, too
        if isinstance(each, list):
            # this will reuse your "plist" and loop over any nested list again
            plist(each, n)
        # if n matches any element in the list, return True
        if any(n in each_letter for each_letter in each):
            return True
    # if after looping over your list + nested list, return False if no match is find
    else:
        return False

>> lst = ['o', ['hello', 'c', 'bye']]
>> plist(lst, 'o')
>> True
>> plist(lst, 'h')
>> True
>> plist(lst, 'z')
>> False
```

Hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is a one line lambda**:

```
any(list(map(lambda x: True if n in str(x) else False,lst )))
```

**data:**

```
lst=['o','hello', 1]
n='o'
```

**output 1:**

```
True
```

**note:**

`any()` checks if any `True`, then `True` - otherwise `False` - so without the `any()` we get:

`list(map(lambda x: True if n in str(x) else False,lst ))`

**output 2:**

```
[True, True, False]
```