# Python - check if a two specific words are exists in different items in list

Tags: python, string

I have many lists that are more or less similar to this:

```
['my_name:Ruth','my_age:23','hobbies:everything']
```

I want to verify that all the list contains "my_age" and my_name", so if list has only "my_name" but doesn't have "my_age", or opposite, or, doesn't have any of the specificed string, it will be appended to list named "bad". If the list has both "my_age" and my_name", I'll append it to the good list.

for now I have been able to [find only if the list has one of the string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26355191/python-check-if-a-letter-is-in-a-list) :

```
def find_letter(letter, lst):
    return any(letter in word for word in lst)
find_letter('my_name'  , first3)
>>>True
```

But I couldn't put in one code both options. How can I do this?

Comment: A dictionary would be much better suited for this data.

Comment: I don't know what you're really trying to accomplish, of course, but it sounds like it would make more sense to restructure the code overall and use a list with dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine `all` with `any`:

```py
l = ['my_name:Ruth','my_age:23','hobbies:everything']
check = ('my_age', 'my_name')
good = all(any(x in s for s in l) for x in check)
```